# to display xml file through html page by hyperlinking it

Tags: python, html, xml, linux, ubuntu

I have created an app in django that searches the word entered by the user in 10 xml documents. As soon as he enters the word, for the results it is directed to the page that contains the list + graphical charts to represent the frequency of words for each xml file.

my html code:

```
<body BGCOLOR = #9ACD32">
<ul> 
{% for l in list1 %}
      <li> {<a href="/home/pooja/Desktop/{{l.file_name}}/">{l.file_name}}, {{l.frequency_count}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
```

One can see that I'm hyperlinking the the xml file. But when I click on the link, it is not getting displayed. Basically, I want that the list which is getting displayed has the hyperlinks of the xml files and when user clicks on it he can see that file's contents. How can I do that ?I'm new to xml files and django,. So,

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upload the said file to your webserver and then link to that file.. eg

/www/folder/{{l.file.name}}/">

You're currently calling it locally

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the path to the file on your local file system, you need to use the URL that your webserver maps onto the file (you may need to move the files or reconfigure your webserver to make them available over HTTP).